# Vertical alignment flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment, centering

I am trying to place child elements in parent element using flexbox like in this image -- >
https://ibb.co/Wpph8fP.

I know that this is possible by doing three columns then use flex, then flex-column in the first column and center other two vertically.

The thing is, that I need do this in one parent div. 4th element is wrapped and it creates column with 1st element, then I need to center vertically two other elements.

This is what I have already done:

`the code is here` https://codepen.io/MrEyelet/pen/wLxygN?editors=1100

Comment: Please don't use external sites like Codepen to show your code. Instead, because your HTML and CSS is simple enough, you can [edit] your question to include your code as a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/2605758).

Answer (score 1):

1. To use one flex, first set `flex-direction` to column and set wrap to`flex-wrap`.
2. And, the part that needs to be on two lines has a variable height to avoid line breaks.
3. Next, set the `flex` property to `none`, setting `margin` enough to make a line break in the part that needs to be on one line. This will force flex items to break and keep the size of the item.

   > ### flex - Values<sup>[[mdn]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex#none)</sup>
   >
   > `none`
   >   The item is sized according to its `width` and `height` properties. It is fully inflexible: it neither shrinks nor grows in relation to the flex container. This is equivalent to setting `"flex: 0 0 auto"`.

```css
body {
  background: tomato;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 100vh;
}

.child {
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  background: indigo;
}


/* add below */
.child:nth-of-type(-n+2) {
  flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 40px);
}


/* add below */
.child:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  flex: none;
  margin: 50% 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child-1">
  </div>
  <div class="child child-2">
  </div>
  <div class="child child-3">
  </div>
  <div class="child child-4">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Did this solution not solve your problem? If so, please tell me more details.

Comment: Yes, the answer is usefull. But now for example when I add two more divs (child 5 and child 6) I would like to have two more columns with the divs one above the other, like in the first col.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. 

I got one more question. Is it possibile to have 1 or 2 or 3 childs only in one row and then, when somebody add next div it wraps to new line creating column and the two  other divs are centered vertically.

And the when 5th div is added it wraps creating second column and the last div is vertically centered.

And finally the same with 6th added div.